# .NET: What is the best way to submit a user-defined tag to WebClient's UploadStringCompletedEventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

... so multiple simultaneous server responses can be contextualized, if I want to reuse the handler?

```
    var fileDownload1 = new WebClient();
    string myPostData1 = ...;
    string tag1 = "download1";   // <-- where do I put it?
    fileDownload1.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(OnFileDonwloadRequestCompleted);
    fileDownload1.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.somewhereinthe.net"), httpverb, myPostData1);

    ....

    var fileDownload2 = new WebClient();
    string myPostData2 = ...;
    string tag2 = "download2";   // <-- where do I put it?
    fileDownload2.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(OnFileDonwloadRequestCompleted);
    fileDownload2.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.somewhereinthe.net"), httpverb, myPostData2);

    ....

void OnFileDonwloadRequestCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string tag = ???? ;   // <-- where can I get it?
    switch (tag)
    {
    case "download1": 
        ...
        break;
    case "download2":
        ...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a field in your class instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to identify which upload call triggered your callback function:

Use the overload with the fourth parameter `object userToken` in your [`UploadStringAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144241(v=vs.110).aspx) method call:

```
 fileDownload1.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.somewhereinthe.net"), 
                                                     httpverb, myPostData1, "download1");
```

and in the `OnFileDonwloadRequestCompleted` method use the UserState property to get that value back:

```
string tag = (string)e.UserState;
```